Will Expo File System Reset when Having an Update from Play Store?
I have an React Native (Expo) project. I use expo-file-system to store my data in files created by the app. If I publish an update on Play Store and user get this update will the data files be removed or not? It's very necessary for my project.
Theese are the locations where I store data files.
export const focusDBPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "focusDB.json"
export const tagDBPath = FileSystem.documentDirectory + "tagDB.json"

If the data at risk how can I prevent the data from removing?

FileSystem.documentDirectory is an application specific folder and persistent. Use a relative url to access files as an absolute url might change after update. There is also FileSystem.cacheDirectory which is automatically cleared by the OS.

Files stored here will remain until explicitly deleted by the app.


When I remove and install app again the data is cleared. How can I solve it?

Your original question was about the update. It is not the same thing as removing and installing again.
